# Displaying clickable URL's in my users created comments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to Rails and I am not 100% sure as to how I can implement the following function. In my Rails app, my users can create posts and comment on those posts, but how can I show clickable URLs if a user puts not only text but also URL's in a comment that they create. Here is my posts `show.html.erb` template.

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h4>All Comments</h4>
</div>

<% @post.newest_comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class="comments">
    <h5><%= comment.body %></h5>
      <li>
       <small class="muted">
        posted by <%= link_to comment.creator.username %> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) + ' ago' %>
        <% if logged_in? && (comment.creator == current_user) %> |
        <%= link_to 'edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) %> |
          <i class="icon-user icon"></i>
        <% end %>
      </small>
      </li>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've have been using this gem with much success-
https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

### Update

You don't need to add require to your controller. Now that you have the gem in your Gemfile you are able to do something like this in your view-

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h4>All Comments</h4>
</div>

<% @post.newest_comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class="comments">
    <h5><%= auto_link(comment.body) %></h5> # this link with the auto link helper
      <li>
       <small class="muted">
        posted by <%= link_to comment.creator.username %> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) + ' ago' %>
        <% if logged_in? && (comment.creator == current_user) %> |
        <%= link_to 'edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) %> |
          <i class="icon-user icon"></i>
        <% end %>
      </small>
      </li>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Have a look and try to understand the documentation over here https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink#synopsis it demonstrates different way you are able to use it in your views.

Comment: Thanks, I've already updated my gem file with but I'm not sure where to go from there. I updated the gem, re-started the server and added `require 'rails_autolink'`to my posts_controller. Where do I go from there? I don't understand the instructions and I actually am not familiar with gems.